# change data in column 0 of dataset before binding to asp.net repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, repeater

I have a dataset that is bound to an asp.net repeater control

One of the columns is a url to an open graph image for external pages.

I store the url in my database, but have found some stop displaying after a while, presumably because the image url has changed. Therefore, I'd like to check that the graph image url is returning a response, and if not then return my placeholder url instead. I DO NOT want to replace the url in my database, in case it's a temporary issue - I don't want to lose the original url.

Assuming my code to create the dataset is:

```
SqlCommand countMostRead = new SqlCommand(getMostread, dbcon);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(countMostRead);
        da.Fill(ds);
        rptLatest.DataSource = ds;
        rptLatest.DataBind();
```

And the graph image url is the first column in the dataset, is there a way to check the dataset column 0 for each row and change it if the graph image url doesn't exist?

i am thinking that I would need to run a foreach on column0, run my httpweb request

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "HEAD";

        bool exists;
        try
        {
            request.GetResponse();
            exists = true;
            return exists;
        }
        catch
        {
            exists = false;
            return exists;
        }
```

And change the column data to my placeholder url if the httpwebrequest returns false.

However, I'm unsure IF this is indeed the correct approach, and if so what the correct syntax would be?

Can anyone suggest code for achieving this? Or, if I'm barking up the wrong tree please suggest an alternative approach.

Edit - as a tentative stab, I've tried this:

```
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                string imgURL = row[0].ToString();
                bool graphImageExists = graphImageExists(imgURL);
                if (graphImageExists)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    row[0] = "my placeholder";
                }
            }
        }
```

Where graphImageExists() runs the httpwebrequest. This doesn't return an error, but it doesn't seem to change the data to the placeholder when necessary - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is ok.
As long as you are not trying to download the file, you can use HttpWebRequest to send a HEAD request(to check that the file exists) :

```
HttpWebResponse resp = null;
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("the URL");
req.Method = "HEAD";
resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

If you get an WebException, it means the file is not there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Apologies - I don't see that's any different to what I'm already doing, no? But if I get a response that the file isn't there (bool graphImageExists = false) then my code 'code'row[0] = "my placeholder"; doesn't seem to be bound to the repeater

Comment: If you wanted only a confirmation, yes, your solution should work.

Comment: no, i want to replace the data with my placeholder url if the image doesn't exist at the url in my database.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand now. Your issue seems to be that you are trying to change the url after you databind the source of the repeater. Try to make the url check before you databind the source of the repeater; if not possible, use the Repeater.ItemDataBound Event 
(
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx )

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. So on the itemdatabound event, i would do foreach image, check the url and if httpwebrequest is false then change the image url?

Comment: On itemdatabound event you only check the current row; yes, you can check the url and change it if it's not vlaid . But, if I were you, I would validate the urls before databind.

Comment: could you help me out codewise? i'm pretty stuck on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure itemdatabound event is called.
2. Put this code into the event :

   ```
           string imgURL = row[0].ToString();
           bool graphImageExists = graphImageExists(imgURL);
           if (graphImageExists)
           {

           }
           else
           {
               row[0] = "my placeholder";
           }
   ```

Comment: thanks - am getting an error that row doesn't exist in the current context?

Comment: Check this MSDN link on how to use the itemdatabound event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sorry, i didn't have a chance to look at it yesterday, am having a look at the link now... I've kind of resolved it in a hacky way, i was only having a problem with one external site, and now for that only site i retrieve the twitter:image rather than the og:image and it works, but i'm aware that's not a long term solution because for that site the og:image used to work